# I want to combine certain line items of data into one tab

Tags: excel, vba

I run an audit at work which can return several million line items of data.  So excel gives me many tabs of 65,536 line items on each tab. I have the vba code which will combine all data onto one tab but again this won't work because of the row limits for each tab.  Therefore I only want certain line items being pulled out.

I only want to include the line items where the Field Name is Position is Using Time.  I am new to VBA and assume that I should specify that within the Loop?

So (within the code listed below) I need to include For every time the Field Name equals Position is Using Time I want that entire line item to be dropped into the new Audit Trail tab. I have included an example of the line item I am looking for within each tab, and also a copy of the code I use for combining smaller audit trails.

Any help is very much appreciated!  Thank you.

Example of line item I need to pull from the data
[image]

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
    Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object 
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
    Dim trg As Worksheet 'Audit Trail Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 'Range object
    Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

     'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
    Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
     'Rename the new worksheet
    trg.Name = "Audit Trail"

     'Get column headers from the first worksheet
     'Column count first
    Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
    colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column

     'Retrieve Headers
    With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
        .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
         'Set font as bold
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

     'Start loop
    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

         'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
        If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
            Exit For
        End If
         'Data range in worksheet - starts from 1st row as headers are only in first tab.
        Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))

         'Put data into the Master worksheet
        trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
    Next sht

     'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
    trg.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: what's your Excel version?

Comment: I am using 2016 so thank you for letting me know about the Power Pivot.  That will be really helpful for me.  However, for this particular instance the auditors that I work for want to be able to pull the raw data and then be able to run the VBA code in order to pull the required line items as they want to keep the initial dataset as untouched as possible.

Comment: Power Query does not destroy the initial data set. Your audit trail will stay intact. You can do the Power Query/Power Pivot analysis in a completely separate workbook. If your auditors don't understand the Excel Power tools, they should upskill.

Answer (score 0):

The 64K row limit went away with Excel 2007. It's over a million rows since that version. With Power Pivot (XL 2010 and later), you can load a LOT more rows than that into the data model. Looping through all that data with VBA will be painfully slow. Using modern tools like Power Query, you can combine the data from all sheets and set filters. That will run a LOT faster.